# How do I compile Rust 0.10 with multiple closures sharing a captured variable?

Tags: rust

Since upgrading to Rust 0.10 today I've found this code no longer works:

```
let mut outer_value = 0;

let add = |x| {
    outer_value += x;
};

let multiply = |x| {
    outer_value *= x;
};

//Showing commented code to demonstrate intent
//add(4);
//multiply(6);
//println!("{:d}", outer_value);
```

This gives me these compiler errors:

```
closures.rs:13:20: 15:6 error: cannot borrow `outer_value` as mutable more than once at a time
closures.rs:13     let multiply = |x| {
closures.rs:14         outer_value *= x;
closures.rs:15     };
closures.rs:14:9: 14:20 note: borrow occurs due to use of `outer_value` in closure
closures.rs:14         outer_value *= x;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
closures.rs:9:15: 11:6 note: previous borrow of `outer_value` occurs here due to use in closure; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `outer_value` until the borrow ends
closures.rs:9     let add = |x| {
closures.rs:10         outer_value += x;
closures.rs:11     };
closures.rs:22:2: 22:2 note: previous borrow ends here
closures.rs:6 fn main() {
...
closures.rs:22 }
               ^
error: aborting due to previous error
```

This worked in Rust 0.9. Is there still a way to make this work in some fashion?

Note: I think the Nightly build and 0.10 build are one and the same today (3rd April), but I've tested with both. Same result.

Comment: That worked in Rust 0.9? I guess that's one of the unsoundness bugs that was patched this cycle. That code does indeed require multiple mutable borrows and so the 0.9 behaviour was not correct; the 0.10 behaviour is correct. Can you refactor your code so that this requirement is not necessary? If you can't, you'll need to use `Rc<RefCell<T>>` instead of `T`, to use runtime borrow checking.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Yeah, it's just as part of a simple closures demo for a presentation I'm giving; So I can just break the outer_value into 2 separate values. The example is going to be little uglier this way, but at least it will be better aligned with the true spirit of Rust safety concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That worked in Rust 0.9? I guess that's one of the unsoundness bugs that was patched this cycle.

That code does indeed require multiple mutable borrows and so the 0.9 behaviour was not correct; the 0.10 behaviour is correct.

There are two things you can do:

- refactor your code so that this requirement is not necessary, or
- use `RefCell<T>` instead of `T`, to use runtime borrow checking.
- use `Cell<T>` instead of `T`, maintaining a local copy of the object rather than doing borrowing.

Comment: For simple types (like the primitives, in this case), a `Cell` would work too: `let outer = Cell::new(0); /* ... */  outer.set(outer.get() + x)`. This has the benefit of not having any dynamic borrow failures like a `RefCell`, and is generally more efficient.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that both `RefCell` and `Cell` (and any other value) is captured by reference, i.e. changes in one closure will be seen in the others (and outside), so the `Rc` isn't actually necessary.

Comment: Oh yes—forgot that because of their inner mutability they don't need outer mutability, so they're not exclusive borrows. Changed again!